# create small/big size texts regarding to keyword popularity

Tags: keyword, popularity

I'm sorry if it is a silly question.

I have a list of keywords and want to create a text,
where the keywords are written with the font size regarding to its popularity. By which term should i search forums, for something like this:

#### least popular keyword

## most popular keyword

### popular keyword